# How to update object property in useState hook?

Tags: reactjs

I want to when the user `clicks` `submit button` it should add new `object`.  with the given value which is stored in `list varaible`.It should not delete the old `objects`,only `name Property`  should be added.

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function Add() {
  const [todo, addTodo] = useState([{ name: "cat", time: "2 minutes ago" }]);
  const [list, setList] = useState();

 
  const add = () => {
    addTodo({...todo,  todo: {
      name: list
        }})
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={list}
        onChange={(e) => setList(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={add}>Add new</button>
      {todo.map((item, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
          {item.name}
          <span style={{ marginLeft: "15px" }}>{item.time}</span>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your state update is dependent on the previous state value ,its a good practice to make the state updater to have an inline function .

```
addTodo(existingTodos => ([...existingTodos, { name: list}] ))
```

Here we are saying , get the exisitingTodos list and append the new todo along with the exisitingTodos .

```
const add = () => {
    addTodo(existingTodos => ([...existingTodos, { name: list}] ))
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `todo` is an array so you should pass an array when call `addTodo`

```
addTodo([
  ...todo,
  {
    name: list,
  },
]);
```